# Go to a specific page when clicking on a notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

How to go to a specific page when clicking on a notification?
I use Firebase console to push the notification
I used like this. but it didn't work

```
fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
  if(data.wasTapped){
this.navcntrl.push(MessagePage); 
  };
})
```

How i can do it correctly?

My full code: app.component.ts

```
 export class MyApp {
      @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

      rootPage: any = HomePage;
      pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
      constructor(public platform: Platform,private fcm: FCM, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

        fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
          this.nav.push(ListPage)
        })
        this.initializeApp();
        this.pages = [
          { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
          { title: 'List', component: ListPage }
        ];

      }

      initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

          this.statusBar.styleDefault();
          this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }

      openPage(page) {

        this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please help me Its an urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue.
You have to add the property “click_ action”: “FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY” to the “notification” object in order to properly use the background method.

Example:

```
{
 "to" : "tokenHere",
 "notification" : {
     "title": "title",
     "body" : "message",
     "sound": "default",
     "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
 },
 "data": {
    "content": "whatever",
 },
 "priority":"high"
}
```

and use FCM API. Don’t use firebase console.

Comment: Hi, how can you open a specific page? If I want to open a specific page, how do you link it with it? Where is the page class name? Would you please elaborate more?